# Obtain "None" values after specifying schema and reading json file in pyspark

Tags: json, apache-spark-sql

I have a file on s3 in json format(filename=a). I read it and create a dataframe (df) using sqlContext.read.json. On checking df.printSchema; the schema is not what I want. So I specify my own schema with double and string type.

Then I reload the json data in a dataframe (df3) specifying the above schema but when I do df3.head(1) I see "None" values for some of my variables.

See code below -

```
df = sqlContext.read.json(os.path.join('file:///data','a'))
print df.count()
df.printSchema()
df.na.fill(0)
```

After specifying my own schema (sch). Since the schema code is long I haven't included it here.

```
sch=StructType(List(StructField(x,DoubleType,true),StructField(y,DoubleType,true)))

f = sc.textFile(os.path.join('file:///data','a'))
f_json = f.map(lambda x: json.loads(x))    
df3 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(f_json, sch)
df3.head(1)
[Row(x=85.7, y=None)]
```

I obtain **'None' values for all my columns with DoubleType (datatype)** when I do df3.head(1).Am I doing something wrong when I reload the df3 dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to take care of "None" by doing df.na.fill(0)!